# Dexopt error on Android tablet devidce

Tags: android, android-studio, dexopt

I try to run my Android project on my Tablet "Samsung GT-P1000" device but, any time I try to run the App I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBppD.png) massage.

And at the Logcat:
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.helloworld 
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] 
I saw many answer here but none of them worked for me.
I`m working with Android studio (and not eclipse !), I already deleted all my previous Apps from the device and clean/rebuild the project several tims...

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the full output from logcat from when you try to install.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBarta this is the full logcat -  Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_p1000-3930320072ED00EC
Uploading file
 local path: C:\Users\Name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.helloworld 
Installing com.helloworld 
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.helloworld"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.helloworld 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.helloworld 
Unknown failure

Comment: Have you tried using adb command and manually force uninstall?